# Enable and disable submit button depends the value of Viewbag

Tags: html, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am trying to Enable or Disable the submit button depends the value of Viewbag.IsBtnEnabled. If Viewbag.IsBtnEnabled = 'Y' or Viewbag.IsBtnEnabled=null it should be enabled else the submit btn should be disabled. My code is working except null value. Here is my code

```html
<div class="center-block col-sm-6">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="btnSave"
             name="submit" @(ViewBag.IsBtnEnabled == "Y" ? "" : "disabled")>
         Save
     </button>
</div>
```

Comment: So just check if it’s null?

Comment: How can I give else condition there @(ViewBag.IsBtnEnabled == "Y" or null

Comment: Try `@(ViewBag.IsBtnEnabled == "Y" ? "" : (ViewBag.IsBtnEnabled == null ? "" : "disabled"))`

Answer (score 0):

> If Viewbag.IsBtnEnabled = 'Y' or Viewbag.IsBtnEnabled=null it should be enabled else the submit btn should be disabled.

To achieve the requirement, you can try following code snippet.

```
<div class="center-block col-sm-6">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="btnSave"
            name="submit" @((ViewBag.IsBtnEnabled == "Y" || ViewBag.IsBtnEnabled == null) ? "" : "disabled")>

        Save

    </button>

</div>
```